# Why am I getting some random values after the output?

Tags: c, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k;
    scanf("%d",&k);
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
    {
        char num[10];
        scanf("%s",&num);
        int x = num[0]-'0';
        int sum;
        int y;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(num[i]=='\0')
            {
                y = num[i-1]-'0';
                sum = x+y;
                printf("%d\n",sum);
            }
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program is to obtain the sum of first and last digit of a given number. I am getting some random values after the output. Can anyone please explain me this and how do I eliminate it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcP4G.png)

Comment: What are you entering for input? I bet 10 is too small for the input buffer size.

Comment: The last character in a null-terminated byte string is at index `strlen(num) - 1`. You don't need your inner loop.

Comment: `scanf("%s",  &num)` to `scanf("%9s", number)` to use the right pointer and prevent buffer overflow

Comment: regarding: `char num[10];
        scanf("%s",&num);`  In C, a bare reference to an array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So this: `scanf("%s",&num);` is asking for the address of an address.  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.  Suggest: `scanf("%s",num);`  Notice no `&` before the array name

Comment: @user3629249 -- Array identifiers decay to pointers in _most_ expressions, but they _do not_ decay to pointers when they are operands of the unary `&` operator. In this case the address of the array is returned. It is still wrong here, not because it is an address of an address, but rather because the type is wrong, i.e. it is the address of an _array_.

Answer (score 2):

You have an inner loop that looks for the terminating null byte in the array.  You find it, but then you keep looping through the array looking for more null bytes.  If you happen to find one, it takes whatever the prior byte is and treats it as the last digit.

You can fix this by breaking out of the loop when you find the null terminator:

```
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(num[i]=='\0')
        {
            y = num[i-1]-'0';
            sum = x+y;
            printf("%d\n",sum);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Or by simply using `strlen` to find the end of the string.

```
    y = num[strlen(num)-1]-'0';
    sum = x+y;
    printf("%d\n",sum);
```

The code also doesn't handle reading too many characters, which can overflow the buffer, or reading an empty string, in which case `num[strlen(num)-1]` is off the start of the array.  You can address the former by putting a field width in the `scanf` format, and the latter with an explicit check:

```
    char num[10];
    scanf("%9s",num);
    int sum;
    if (num[0] == 0) {
        sum = 0;
    } else {
        int x = num[0]-'0';
        int y = num[strlen(num)-1]-'0';
        sum = x + y;
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
```

Comment: What happens if num is an empty string?

Comment: @EdHeal Added code to check for overflow/underflow.

Comment: You do not need & in front of num

Comment: @EdHeal It's there: `if (num[0] == 0)`

Comment: Should sum be zero in that case

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't stop the inner loop once you print the sum. You continue and use the indeterminate elements in the array `num` beyond the string terminator. That leads to *undefined behavior*.

You could solve it either by not having the inner loop (by using index `0` and `strlen(num) - 1`), or by using `break` to break out of the loop once you printed the sum.